# Differences in parsing json with a custom unmarshaller between golang versions

Tags: json, go

I am trying to port some code written against go1.3 to current versions and ran into a case where the json parsing behavior is different between versions. We are using a custom unmarshaller for parsing some specific date format. It looks like recent versions pass in the string with additional quotes which 1.3 did not.

Is this a bug or an intentional change? And whats the best way of writing code which is compatible with different versions in this situation. Just go looking for all places where a custom unmarshaller is in use always strip out extra quotes if any? It would be a pity to have to do that - so I am hoping there is a better way.

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"
import "time"

type Timestamp1 time.Time

func (t *Timestamp1) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    fmt.Println("String to parse as timestamp:", string(b))
    parsedTime, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05", string(b))
    if err == nil {
        *t = Timestamp1(parsedTime)
        return nil
    } else {
        return err
    }
}

type S struct {
    LastUpdatedDate Timestamp1 `json:"last_updated_date,string"`
}

func main() {
    s := `{"last_updated_date" : "2015-11-03T10:00:00"}`
    var s1 S
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &s1)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(s1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was [a bug](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9812) concerning `json:",string"` tag that was fixed in 1.5. If there isn't a particular reason you need it, you can remove it and simply adjust your format:

```
// N.B. time is in quotes.
parsedTime, err := time.Parse(`"2006-01-02T15:04:05"`, string(b))
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/LgWuKcPEuI.

This should work in 1.3 as well as 1.5.

Comment: So, basically, ",string" is unusable (or at least badly implemented) on anything other than basic types (strings, floats, integers, and
booleans). I am concluding that all code should just avoid it?

Comment: Not all code, just the code that should support prior versions. This is unfortunate, but this is a bug, and [bugs will be fixed even if they break code expecting the wrong behaviour](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat#expectations).

Comment: Sure. The only point I was making was that if the annotation does nothing on complex types in newer versions, there is not much point in continuing to use it only to target older versions. Anyway, I am largely on the same page as you I think. And I now understand what I need to do thanks to your explanation. Thanks!